# Why does this Promise.all() function only return the last resolved value?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, axios

I'm trying to make a persistent shopping cart on React Native. It works if you only have one item added, but if you add another one, all of the items become the same as the last one you added. I narrowed it down to our getData() function, which returns the data of the products that we render.

```
  async getData(cartItems){
    let promises = []
    cartItems.forEach(item => {
      promises.push(productInfo(item.id))
    })
    return Promise.all(promises)
  }
```

And productInfo() looks like this.

```
export function productInfo(product_id){
  vapeBluntPOST.url = baseUrl+'/api/productinfo'
  vapeBluntPOST.data.id = product_id 
  return axios(vapeBluntPOST).then(({data})=>(data))
}
```

The problem seems to be that the elements of the array returned by Promise.all() are all the same as the last resolved value corresponding to the last promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `vapeBluntPOST`, which is not locally scoped within `productInfo`. So by the time the promises resolve, they are all using that from the last call, which comes from the last id in the array.

Assuming you don't actually need that object elsewhere, the easy fix is to just use a local variable instead:

```
export function productInfo(product_id){
  const vapeBluntPOST = { /* common configuration that you need */};
  vapeBluntPOST.url = baseUrl+'/api/productinfo'
  vapeBluntPOST.data.id = product_id 
  return axios(vapeBluntPOST).then(({data})=>(data))
}
```